# Using UITextViews as UITextFields

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextview

This is my first question.

I'm currently working on an iOS app in Swift. I was previously using three UITextFields for users to enter their data (it's a journaling app), but I hadn't realized that UITextField was limited to one line.

I've worked on getting three UITextViews to behave like UITextFields, except for one thing. I was using the code below to detect if the user pressed the return key so that they could begin typing in the next TextView (like the way that the return key behaves with multiple TextFields).

My one problem is that when the cursor moves down to the next TextView, it brings the new line ("\n") with it! I've tried many different ways to fix this and nothing seems to be working. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Matt

```
func textView(textView: UITextView!, shouldChangeTextInRange: NSRange, replacementText: NSString!) {
    if(replacementText == "\n") {
        if(textView == firstTextView) 
        {
            firstTextView.resignFirstResponder()
            secondTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
        }

        if(textView == secondTextView)
        {
            secondTextView.resignFirstResponder()
            thirdTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
        }

        if(textView == thirdTextView)
        {
            thirdTextView.resignFirstResponder()
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, `textView(_:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:)` [must return `Bool` value](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:):

> ```
> optional func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool
> ```

And when you return `false`, it cancels the change of the text. So I think you should:

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if(replacementText == "\n") {

        // ...

        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that sounds like it could be right to me, but now I'm getting this error: 

Type '()' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanLiteralConvertible'

Comment: Just add `-> Bool` return type to the function signature.